# using variables from styles.scss into components. Angular4

Tags: angular, variables, sass

I am creating an Angular4 with typescript Application and having problems with .scss files. 
I have a file called src/styles/_1_colors.scss. and I use this style in all files.

The styles.scss file is working correctly and already had been added to the angular-cli

I wrote this inside styles.scss:

> @import "styles/_1_colors";

and it does not give me an error, so the path is correct. 
I am trying to use a variable that exists in _1_colors called: $bms_darkblue
inside a file called src/app/search/query/query.component.scss. and I am receiving this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/search/query/query.component.scss
Module build failed:
       color: $bms_darkblue;
             ^
      Undefined variable: "$bms-darkblue".
```

but I do not understand why everything seems to be correct.
any ideas could help. 
I think the problem is that the component.scss is being loaded before the styles.scss.

if you may provide me with some sources or explanations that would be better. 
thank you!

Comment: You should add the import in `query.component.scss`

Comment: why? I want to make it global. that means I want to add it one time to my code and be visible to all other files

Comment: That is not possible by my knowledge, and goes against the component/module based philosophy of Angular

Comment: himmm, can you please (if you have) provide me with some resources?

Comment: you can read this issue :) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1253

Answer (score 0):

```
src/styles/_1_colors.scss
src/app/search/query/query.component.scss
```

I see that your file `query.component.scss` is not under `/styles` folder. So you might have to import `_1_colors.scss` as per your folder structure.

Comment: I know that and I did it, but I am trying to find a way to add it globally one time only to all other components